# Can funds sent to an invalid usdt wallet address be lost?

Tags: erc-20

I had to receive usdt but the sender made a blunder in that the wallet address was missing one letter in the middle.and the sender said that the funds have been lost

Comment: Yes your money is lost forever.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.